# Answering difficult questions about the state of humanity

Tags: political-philosophy, human-condition

My child is at that age of asking difficult questions.

Things like

```
How come Japan has suffered two nuclear attacks and is still one of the largest economies in the world?
```

Or

```
How come people in Africa still live in mud houses and starve on a regular basis?
```

What good explanations are there for this difference besides race?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.

Comment: Maybe [parenting.SE](http://parenting.stackexchange.com) would be a better place to ask?

Comment: Be honest - say we do not know, and maybe she will find the answer.

Comment: The question as asked is off-topic, but there are probably related on-topic questions.

Comment: If s/he is old enough to be interested in these questions, then s/he is probably old enough to understand, at a basic level, that economic and political institutions (e.g. the enforcement of property rights, the rule of law, the ease of starting businesses) have a lot to do with prosperity.  You can tell your child that there are people called economists who devote their lives to these questions, that they've figured out a lot but haven't yet figured out everything, and that if these questions continue to fascinate your child, s/he might find a career in this someday.